# Data Feed for Space Weather / Aurora

Tags: data, leaflet, weather, georss

I am building a map application for a northerly area and would love to bring in a feed of northern lights prediction/probability (like below). 
http://www.gi.alaska.edu/AuroraForecast

Does anyone know of a service for space weather that I could digest into leaflet or something?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you know how to interpret the data you are asking for.  These guys post the data daily and you can calc some polygons for a pretty map graphic.

http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/ftpdir/lists/hpi/
http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/pmap/Plots.html

Comment: looks like these links are broken